# Show notification even app is close flutter

Tags: flutter, notifications, background, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

I want my application to always show in a notification .It should be undismissable and it should be shown on notification bar always even app is off.

Answer (score 0):

Try [flutter_local_notifications](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_local_notifications) plugin.

Comment: Can you share the code.

Comment: Plese check the link, I've shared. In the example section they've given necessary codes.

Answer (score 0):

If you didn't find a plugin that satisfies your needs, just implement it on the native side.

Flutter is a UI framework. Use it as such.

Plugins wrap native capabilities and encapsulate them, but feel free to add native code that suits your needs.

Comment: please provide some code i am new in flutter

Comment: I assume you know Android. Open the Android folder in your project with your IDE. This is a standard Android project, only the main activity inherits from FlutterActivity, so it runs flutter. Now add the Android notification https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications

You should do the same for iOS (open ios folder with xcode)